# gstreamer pipeline error while trying to stream video from webcam

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

I am trying to get h264 frames from webcam, here is the code. I am getting runtime error. Can anybody help please.

**Code:**

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef char bool;

typedef struct _CustomData {
    GstElement *pipeline, *source, *source_filter, *encoder, *filter, *appsink, *videorate;
    GstBus *bus;
    GMainLoop *main_loop;
} CustomData;

static GstFlowReturn on_new_sample(GstElement *sink, CustomData *data) {

    static int i = 0;
    printf("frame %d", i++);

    return GST_FLOW_OK;
}

static void error_cb(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    /* Print error details on the screen */
    gst_message_parse_error(msg, &err, &debug_info);
    g_printerr("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
    g_printerr("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
    g_clear_error(&err);
    g_free(debug_info);

    g_main_loop_quit(data->main_loop);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  CustomData data;
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    bool vtenc;

    /* init data struct */
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));

    /* init GStreamer */
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    /* create the elemnents */
    /*
       gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=1280,height=720,framerate=15/1 ! x264enc pass=quant bframes=0 ! video/x-h264,profile=baseline,format=I420,width=1280,height=720,framerate=15/1 ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mkv
     */
    data.source_filter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "source_filter");
    data.filter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "encoder_filter");
    data.appsink = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "appsink");
    data.videorate = gst_element_factory_make("videorate", "videorate");

    // Attempt to create vtenc encoder
    data.encoder = gst_element_factory_make("vtenc_h264_hw", "encoder");
    if (data.encoder) {
        data.source = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosrc", "source");
        vtenc = 1;
    } else {
        // Failed creating vtenc - attempt x264
        data.encoder = gst_element_factory_make("x264enc", "encoder");
        data.source = gst_element_factory_make("v4l2src", "source");
        vtenc = 0;
    }

    /* create an empty pipeline */
    data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("test-pipeline");

    if (!data.pipeline || !data.source || !data.source_filter || !data.encoder || !data.filter || !data.appsink || !data.videorate) {
        g_printerr("Not all elements could be created.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* configure source */
    if (!vtenc) {
        g_object_set(G_OBJECT (data.source), "device", "/dev/video0", NULL);
    }

    /* source filter */
    GstCaps *source_caps = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw",
                                               "width", G_TYPE_INT, 640,
                                               "height", G_TYPE_INT, 480,
                                               "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
                                               NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT (data.source_filter), "caps", source_caps, NULL);
    gst_caps_unref(source_caps);

    /* configure encoder */
    if (vtenc) {
        g_object_set(G_OBJECT (data.encoder), "allow-frame-reordering", FALSE, "realtime", TRUE, "max-keyframe-interval",
                          45, "bitrate", 512, NULL);
    } else {                
        g_object_set(G_OBJECT (data.encoder), "bframes", 0, "key-int-max", 45, "bitrate", 512, NULL);
    }

    /* configure filter */
    GstCaps *h264_caps = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-h264",
                                             "profile", G_TYPE_STRING, "baseline",
                                             "stream-format", G_TYPE_STRING, "avc",
                                             "alignment", G_TYPE_STRING, "au",
                                             "width", G_TYPE_INT, 640,
                                             "height", G_TYPE_INT, 480,
                                             "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
                                             NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT (data.filter), "caps", h264_caps, NULL);
    gst_caps_unref(h264_caps);

    /* configure appsink */
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT (data.appsink), "emit-signals", TRUE, "sync", FALSE, NULL);
    g_signal_connect(data.appsink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK(on_new_sample), &data);

    /* build the pipeline */
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN (data.pipeline), data.source,  data.videorate, data.source_filter, data.encoder, data.filter, 
        data.appsink, NULL);
    if (gst_element_link_many(data.source,  data.videorate, data.source_filter, data.encoder, data.filter, data.appsink, NULL) != TRUE) {
        g_printerr("Elements could not be linked.\n");
        gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Instruct the bus to emit signals for each received message, and connect to the interesting signals */
    data.bus = gst_element_get_bus(data.pipeline);
    gst_bus_add_signal_watch(data.bus);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(data.bus), "message::error", (GCallback) error_cb, &data);
    gst_object_unref(data.bus);

    /* start streaming */
    ret = gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
        g_printerr("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
        return 1;
    }

    data.main_loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    g_main_loop_run(data.main_loop);

    /* free resources */
    gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);

  return 0;
}
```

**Compile:**

> gcc gst_test.c -o gst_test -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0
>   -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0

**Error:**

> Error received from element source: Internal data flow error.
>   Debugging information: gstbasesrc.c(2948): gst_base_src_loop ():
>   /GstPipeline:test-pipeline/GstV4l2Src:source: streaming task paused,
>   reason not-negotiated (-4)

Comment: Does your webcam support capture in I420? Maybe you need to capture it in another format and put a videoconverter before the encoding. There is definitely something wrong with your caps.

Comment: yes it does support. The gstreamer pipeline 

"gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=1280,height=720,framerate=15/1 ! x264enc pass=quant bframes=0 ! video/x-h264,profile=baseline,format=I420,width=1280,height=720,framerate=15/1 ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mkv" 

works fine

Comment: Does it do 640x480? Your launch line is different from what you do in the code. Maybe it would be easier to use `gst_parse_launch()`? That would also reduce much of the code and you could still access elements via `gst_bin_find_by_name()` if needed. Also the width, height and framrate seem redundant after the encoder.